# JS код и таблица Google

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

В JavaScript я полный новичок, но хочу сделать очень удобный для меня код. Ломаю голову, ищу в интернете, ничего найти не получается.
В общем у меня есть Google таблица с 3 листами. В этих листах, условно список сотрудников с 3-ёх разных подразделений. Можно ли как-то сделать три переменные, ну и соответственно в каждой из будут данные с целого листа (столбца). Допустим в переменной "a" будет список сотрудников с листа 1(столбца), в переменной "b" список сотрудников с листа 2, в "c" соответственно с 3-го.

Comment: Это вроде объект называется

Comment: Это, вроде, заказ на работу называется.

Answer (score 0):

Небольшой пример, по аналогии можете дополнить данными с других листов:

```
function getSheetsData (){

//Открываем активный документ, для доступа по ID файла ипользуем openById вместо getActiveSpreadsheet
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

//Получаем лист 1
const sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName('Имя листа 1');

//Получаем все данные с листа 1 (Массив)
let dataSheet1 = sheet1.getDataRange().getValues();

}
```